# convert/compile a netbeans project to an .exe file

Tags: netbeans, exe

I have a netbeans project and I need to create an `.exe` file out of it.

I want it to run this program on a friends computer who doesn't have netbeans installed.

So how do I do this?

Comment: exactly what project is it? C++, Java? You need to figure out how to **compile** your project

Answer (score 0):

If its a java project then just compile and build the project. go to the project folder->dist folder, copy the .jar file and give it to your friend to use. ur friend needs to have JRE installed on his system.